# Copy elements of one array to another in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

So I am trying to use char array in C to copy from one array to another, each element at a time, however, I am stuck at this part. I did try to research but may be I'm a dumb or what not, I still could not get it right. Here is my code:

Say I have two array

```
char arr1[1000][3]
char arr2[1000][3]
```

So wHat I mean is that [3] equal length of the string and each array has 1000 elements. So `arr1[0] = "AB\0"`

I can't, obviously, do `arr1[i] = arr2[i];` won't work of course, I did try strcpy but don't quite get it right. Please help me out a bit, thank you :)

Here a portion of it, the specific function I writing:
Please just answer the one I ask, I can do this easily in Java but I really learning C so...
An example would be nice :D

```
//build stacks                                                                                                                                                                                                     
card_pos_ptr add_card(card_pos_ptr head, char card_list[1000][3], int index){
  int i,k = 0;
  int start_index = index;
  card_pos_ptr current = head;
  for(i=0;i<13;i++){
    for(k=0;k<4;k++){
      if(current->card_stack == NULL){
        card_ptr node = (card_ptr)malloc(sizeof(card));
    strcpy(node->card_name,);
        node->up = false;
        node->down = NULL;
        start_index++;
      }else{
        card_ptr node = (card_ptr)malloc(sizeof(card));
        //node->card_name[0] = card_list[start_index];                                                                                                                                                             
        node->up = false;
        node->down = current->card_stack;
        current->card_stack = node;
        start_index++;
      }
    }
    current = current->next_pos;
  }

}
```

Comment: [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) ?

Comment: how u do that? Like memcpy(arr1[i], arr2[i], 3);???

Comment: Yeah, but it would be better to copy the entire array with a single call to `memcpy`, unless there's something preventing you from doing that.

Comment: Yes, I don't simply copy one array to another. What I am doing is copy content of each element in the big array and pass it in the small array in the struct.

Comment: I got this warning: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’

Comment: Well, you obviously need to include the necessary header (`string.h`)

Comment: @Rozen its in `<string.h>`, make sure that is included in your file (and I somewhat expected it was, otherwise how are you pulling in `strcpy()`?). So I have to ask. You have a 1000x3 2D-array of what appears to be two-letter strings (third char is the terminator, if I'm correct). Is that thing like a thousand-count card deck? And I'm not surprised `strcpy` didn't work, considering `strcpy(node->card_name,);` isn't even valid C code.

Comment: Yes WhozCraig, that precisely what it is. So each element contain 3 letters, Suits name and A->K, the third one is terminator.

Comment: OK. I get it.  Not how I'd do it, but I get it. Is the entire 1000-element array properly initialized ?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the <string.h> header haha. @WhozCraig, Yes, the entire array initialized. Sorry for the above code, I put the incompleted one cuz I was changing it around to see which one will work. after including the header, it compile fine now. Btw, so the one I using is a 2D array? Not 1D? Also, I guess it is better if I use a char *arra1[1000], but I'm still sux at using pointer, so I have to go with Java style for now... Will dig deeper @ pointer later...

Comment: The 1000x3 is genuine 2D, not to be confused with the pointer-array idiom most people call 2D. this one is actual 2D. The ones in the cards are 1D (obviously). Anyway, assuming each (both the 1000-card shoe and the nodes you're creating) are indeed made of 3-char arrays, there is no reason you can't `memcpy()` or `strcpy()` the data. Since you know they're all 2-char strings with a terminator, `strcpy()` is somewhat pointless. I'd `memcpy()` it over if I was told to do it this way.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thank you for pointing that out, I keep thinking it is 1D and arr1[1000][3], the [3] just to tell the size of each element, not an index itself. My bad... the misunderstanding cost me several hours... Ah, wait a minute, so I better off using strcpy or memcpy in this case?

Comment: Heh. to be completely honest, `memcpy()` is the right call, but since it is literally only three chars I'll honestly be surprised if the compiler doesn't optimize it away entirely and simply unroll to do three single-byte moves. A for-loop would also work (which is what was in your accepted answer).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42477/discussion-between-whozcraig-and-rozen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with this declaration but in frist place to declare array you need something like :

```
  char arr1[1000][3];
  char arr1[0][0] = 'A';
  char arr1[0][0] = 'B';
  ...
```

And in order to copy each element one at a time use a for loop:

```
if ( something that determines X ? ) {
    for ( int i=0; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
       arr2[x][i] = arr1[x][i];
    }
}
```

Comment: No, each element in the char array contains more than 1 char, so it will be AB, not just A or B. Plus I tried assigning like ur example, the compiler say incompatible type assignment.

Comment: 1 dimensional is different from 2 dimensional array

Comment: Like I said i just wasn't sure what was he doing i answered before he edited his question.

Does this help you ?

Comment: This one would work fine too I guess, Beside the one answers under my question :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
int i;
char arr1[1000][3];
char arr2[1000][3];

arr1[0][0]='v';

for(i=0;i<1000;++i)
{
    strncpy(arr2[i],arr1[i],3); //safe copy, copies max. 3 chars.
}

printf("%c\n",arr2[0][0]);
```

Comment: appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try

memcpy( &node->card_name[0] ,card_list[start_index])

Comment: need 3 arguments for memcpy.